# How can I add a font to an iOS app, to be installed globally on the device?

Tags: ios, swift, fonts

I am making an app - a keyboard for a script (Caucasian Albanian) unsupported by iOS. I would like to add a Caucasian Albanian font along with this app, so that users can view the script properly with their device on other apps as well, such as browser or messaging apps. I am well aware of the normal method of including a font with an app, but this only makes the script visible on the app itself, and not in other apps. I am also aware that as of iOS 13, users can install fonts themselves (without any third-party apps to do so) but I would like to make the process more convenient, especially for users of iOS 12 and earlier, who would otherwise have to download a third-party app to add the font.

Comment: This is an interesting question. There are various articles on how to install custom fonts in your app, and There are various user-facing articles online that talk about using font installers to install fonts on your device, but I can't find any Apple documentation on how to build a font installer.